# Why does it matter which pointer is changing the next element in a linked list?

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have been working through some HackerRank challenges. This one is reversing a linked list. I wanted to try it out recursively, which I think I've done well. However, my code wasn't working correctly because of one tiny change:

```
void Reverse(Node *&head)
{
  if (head == NULL)
      return;

  Node *link = head->next;

  if (link == NULL)
      return;

   Reverse(link);
   link->next = head;
   head->next = NULL;
   head = link;
}
```

So this wasn't working. I traced the problem to the first line after the recursive call `reverse(link)`, if I change that line to `head->next->next = head;` the program passes all of the tests. I don't understand the difference between `link->next` and `head->next->next` if we consider that `link` is equal to `head->next`. **Why does it matter which pointer is pointing to head?**

My logic:

```
Given:
--------------------------------------
h     l
|     |
[1]->[2]->[3]
--------------------------------------


link->next = head;
should

 h    l
 |    |
[1]<-[2] [3]


just like

head->next->next = head;

 h   l
 |   |
[1]<-[2] [3]

because head->next-next == link->next
```

Is my logic incorrect? I have a feeling that it has something to do with the fact that I'm recursively calling a function that passes by reference. But when I trace it out, I don't see how that makes a difference in this issue.

Thanks

Comment: But the recursive call to `Reverse` *changes* the value of `link` (it is passed by reference). After that call `link` is no longer `head->next`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - your logic is a bit wrong. Changing the value of head destroys the algorithm. The idea is that after each return, head and link gets their old values back.

Try:

```
void Reverse(Node* head) // Just pass a pointer
{
  if (head == NULL)
      return;

  Node *link = head->next;

  if (link == NULL)
      return;

   Reverse(link);
   link->next = head;
   head->next = NULL;
   // head = link;  Don't change head
}
```

But this still have a problem - how to set the new head after the list has been reversed? You need to catch the pointer to the last element in the original list.

Change like this:

```
void Reverse(Node* p, Node** newHeadAddr)
{
    // Will only happen if list is empty
    if (p == NULL) return;

    Node *link = head->next;

    // If the end is reached
    if (link == NULL) 
    {
         *newHeadAddr = p;
         return;
    }

    Reverse(link, newHead);

    // link now points to last element in reversed list
    // p points to current element
    // so add p to the reversed linked list
    link->next = p;
    p->next = NULL;
}
```

and use it like:

```
Node* newHead = nullptr;
Reverse(head, &newHead);
head = newHead;
```

Regarding the logic: Below is an example of the variables behave as the recursive call goes on, i.e. a description of what p and link is point to at each call. Hope it helps.

**Let assume you have a list of three element.**

At the first call you have:

```
First call:
p is a pointer element[0] (i.e. head)
link is a pointer to element[1]
```

At the second call you have:

```
Second call:
p is a pointer to element[1]
link is a pointer to element[2]
---------------------------------------
First call:
p is a pointer to element[0] (i.e. head)
link is a pointer to element[1]
```

At the third call you have:

```
Third call:
p is a pointer to element[2]
link is a null pointer
---------------------------------------
Second call:
p is a pointer to element[1]
link is a pointer to element[2]
---------------------------------------
First call:
p is a pointer to element[0] (i.e. head)
link is a pointer to element[1]
```

Since link is nullptr the call will return and you have:

```
Second call:
p is a pointer to element[1]
link is a pointer to element[2]
---------------------------------------
First call:
p is a pointer to element[0] (i.e. head)
link is a pointer to element[1]
```

Now code can do

```
link->next = p;     // element[2]->next = element[1]
p->next = nullptr;  // element[1]->next = nullptr;
```

so it has have

```
element[2]->element[1]->nullptr
```

and then the return gives:

```
First call:
p is a pointer element[0]
link is a pointer to element[1]
```

Now code can do

```
link->next = p;     // element[1]->next = element[0]
p->next = nullptr;  // element[0]->next = nullptr;
```

so you have

```
element[2]->element[1]->element[0]->nullptr
```

and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Reverse` isn't an ordinary function. It takes a reference parameter.

Normally if we have some variables, say `x` and `y` which hold the same value or object, and a function `f`, it doesn't matter whether we call `f(x)` or `f(y)`.

But if `f` is not really a function, but actually a function-like syntactic operator which has access to the `x` or `y` *location*, which it overwrites, then it *does* possibly matter whether `x` or `y` is used. It matters because the caller continues to rely on the values of `x` and `y` which have different roles in the continued execution of the caller.

In your (original) program, the `link` variable is equal to `head->next` before the `Reverse(link)` call. But this call modifies `link`, such that after the call, the relationship is no longer the same. If you need to use the prior value of `link`, you must use `head->next`.

One way to avoid the confusion is to use a clear naming for function-like abstractions which do odd things with their arguments, such as clobbering their values. This applies to reference-taking functions as well as preprocessor macros. For instance  if you see `increment(x)`, you are loudly alerted to the possibility that `x` is overwritten with its successor: that `increment` is a reference-taking function, or possibly a preprocessor macro. Whereas if you see `get_account_balance(a)`, you likely don't expect that to overwrite the variable `a`. If it does, that could be the source of a hard-to-spot bug.

Secondly, it goes without saying that you should avoid unnecessary use of reference parameters. There is no reason for your function to have a recursive interface which clobbers its argument.

How you can code the reversal without using a reference parameter is to have the function return the reversed list.  If you still want the reference-based API, you can provide an additional function for that:

```
node *rev_list_destructively(node *list)
{
  if (list == NULL) {
    return NULL; // reversing empty list results in empty list
  } else if (list->next == NULL) {
    return list; // reversing one element list is that list itself
  } else {
    node *rest = list->next;
    node *rest_reversed = rev_list_destructively(rest);

    rest->next = list;
    list->next = NULL;

    return rest_reversed;
  }
}

void rev_list_in_place(node *&list)
{
  list = rev_list_destructively(list);
}
```

Study how the recursion works. If we have a list of at least two elements (`list->next` is not `NULL`), we can call the rest of the list `rest` and reverse that, capturing the return value which gives us the reversed rest. All we have to do is tack the head node onto the tail of this and we are done.

We take advantage of the fact that the original `rest` variable continues to point to the same node as it did before, and that node is now at the end of the list: and so the `rest` pointer now indicates the tail node.

The tail node is the one we need to manipulate in order to extend the tail. We do that  by `rest->next = list`. Now `rest` points to the second-to-last node and `list` is the tail node. `list`, of course, has continued the whole time to point to the original head node of the list that came into the function. To finish up, we must null-terminate the new tail node with `list->next = NULL`. And of course, our return value is the reversed rest list which we captured from the recursive call.

Example:

```
values on entry into recursive case:
  list:  (1 2 3 4)
  rest:  (2 3 4)

after recursion:
  rest_reversed: (4 3 2)
  rest: (2) 
  list: (1 2)  (list->next still points to the (2) node).

after rest->next = list:
  rest_reversed: (4 3 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 ...)   -- list is cyclic!!!
  rest: (2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 ...)
  list: (1 2 1 2 1 ...)

after list->next = NULL
  rest_reversed: (4 3 2 1) -- the cycle is broken!
  rest: (2 1)
  list: (1)

we return rest_reversed: (4 3 2 1).
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a tad mistake in logic.

If be backtrack step-b-step form `NULL` it becomes visible.

*(Assuming `Head` is reference and focusing just on your recursive algorithm.)*

```
[H] = head
[x] = NULL

[H] = [1]

[1] -> [2] -> [3] -> [X] // here link == NULL
                      ^
```

**Pop 0 : Function returns and previous function stack continues**

```
Now when it return the control is at

[1] -> [2] -> [3] -> [X] // The function returns to previous call
               ^
```

Now the next line is

```
link->next = head; 

i.e. [3]->next = head;
i.e.   [3] -> next = [H]
i.e.   [3] -> [1]

head->next = NULL;

i.e.   [3] -> [1] -> [X]   

head = link

i.e [H]=[3]
```

**Pop 1**

Now function returns to this

```
[2] -> [3] -> [1] -> [X]
^      [H]
```

Repeating same steps

```
link->next = head; 

i.e. [2]->next = head;
i.e.   [2] -> next = [H]
i.e.   [2] -> [3]

head->next = NULL;

i.e.   [2] -> [3] -> [X]   // now here we lost access to one
                           // but since its still in recurrsion stack
                           // so no problem

head = link

i.e [H]=[2]
```

**Pop 2**

Now function returns to this

```
[X]->[1]->[X]
      ^
[2] -> [3] -> [X]
[H]
```

Repeating same steps

```
link->next = head; 

i.e. [1]->next = head;
i.e.   [1] -> next = [H]
i.e.   [1] -> [2]
```

Which is correct by far now here comes the error

```
head->next = NULL;


i.e.   [2] -> [X]   // now here we lost access to [3]
head = link

i.e [H]=[1]
```

What linked list we obtained here is

```
[1]->[2]->[x]     [x]->[3]->[X]
[H]
 ^
```

[3] is leaked with no access

**Pop 3 : Final pop to original function call**

Here **link** and **head** are same i.e `[1]`
And everything breaks down

```
link->next = head; 

i.e. [1]->next = head;
i.e.   [1] -> next = [H]
i.e.   [1] -> [1]

head->next = NULL;

i.e.   [1] -> [X]   // now here we lost access to [1]
head = link
[H]=[1]
```

**So finally we have lost the linked list**

```
[1]->[X]   [X]->[2]->[X] [X]->[3]->[X]
```